# Tableau Big Query connector missing from Desktop

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

We have been using Tableau with Big Query connector on our licenced version 10.2.

But since few days we are not finding the Big Query connector on Tableau and hence not able to import the data from Big Query for our dashboard.
[image: Big Query connector not available]

Comment: probably best to reach out to your Tableau support directly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running Tableau Public or Tableau Desktop Personal edition.

You need Tableau Desktop Professional to connect to BigQuery. See: https://www.tableau.com/products/techspecs

If you have Public/Personal and Professional installed make sure that you are running the correct program (it can be confusing since they have very similar icons).

You can easily double check what program you are running by going to:

help -> "About Tableau" and checking to make sure that you see:

[image]

Comment: Yes it was a personal edition. We changed the licence and got the professional one to get it to work. Thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked. If the answer solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted.